# bson_serializer is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bson

I started 'playing' with mongodb and there are some issues I still cannot figure out how to solve them.

Given the following code(taken from the [book](https://www.manning.com/books/node-js-in-action)) :

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var server = new mongodb.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {});

var client = new mongodb.Db('mydatabase', server, {w: 1});
var tmpID = '';

client.open(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    client.collection('test_insert', function(err, collection){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('we are now able to perform queries.');
        collection.insert(
            {
                "title": "I like cake",
                "body": "It is quite good."
            },  
            {safe: true},
            function(err, documents){
                if(err) throw err;
                tmpID = documents.ops[0]._id;               
                console.log('Document ID is: ' + tmpID);
                var _id = new client.bson_serializer.ObjectID(tmpID.toString()); 
                collection.update(
                    {_id: _id},
                    {$set: {"title": "I ate too much cake"}},
                    {safe:true},
                    function(err){
                        if (err) throw err;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    });
});
```

I expect the document which title is "I like cake" to get updated. I get an exception on this line:

`var _id = new client.bson_serializer.ObjectID(tmpID);`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectID' of undefined`

I inspected the `client` object and I see no bson_serializer...

> nodejs 4.2.1
>
> MondoDB 3.0

Related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111123/node-js-mondodb-2-driver-bson-serializer-error-after-updating-mongolab-free-sand

Comment: @KevinB ok, I will remove the tag

Comment: @KevinB btw, I found out the bson_serializar is undefined also inside the callback. It seems to be a problem also with the code. Maybe the tutorial I follow is out of date.